# $(find -X) equivalent on linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to use the bash find command to create an array of elements and search elements inside it with a for loop.
I would need to do something like this:

```
for file in $(find -? dirname) ; do
echo element contains $file
done
```

I know that you can do find -X on mac (which parses spaces and \n as xargs does), but is there any way to do so on linux?
Thank you in advance for your reply

Comment: It's better to use `find -? dirname -exec echo element contains {} \;`. I don't know what -X does in OSX, so I can't help you on that point.

Comment: The OS X documentation says that `-X` makes it skip filenames that would cause problems with `xargs` because they contain whitespace or quotes. The better solution is to use `find -exec` or `find -print0 | xargs -0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OSX `find` manpage says of -X:

> However, you may wish to consider the -print0 primary in conjunction
>   with ``xargs -0'' as an effective alternative.

So you could take that advice:

```
find dirname  -print0 | xargs -0 grep foo  # or whatever it is you wanted to do
```

Alternatively, find can execute a command for each found file itself:

```
find dirname -exec echo found {} \;
```

Note the escaped `;` to terminate -- it's just something you have to suck up about `find -exec`.

Or for xargs-like chunking:

```
find dirname -exec grep foo {} +
```